# Data Structure: Request Counting Task

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I was looking at this programming task and I found the following question.
**Problem Statement**: List of professionals start_time and end_time are given. List of end_tasks for tasks are given. Find the number of tasks each professional can do within his timeframe.

**Inputs**: 
requests: [4,2,5,3,1], start_time: [2,5], end_time:   [5,6].

**Output**:
4 1

**Explanation**: Since Professional_1 has time_frame 2 to 5, he can perform four tasks(4,2,5,3) and Professional_2 has time frame 5 to 6, and he can do only one task(i.e., 5)

Program Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count_requests(int *requests, int requests_length, int *pro_start, int pro_start_length, int *pro_end, int pro_end_length) {

    int i,j,req,start,end,task;
        for(i=0;i<pro_start_length;i++){
            start=*(pro_start+i);
            end=*(pro_end+i);
            task=0;
            for(j=0;j<requests_length;j++){
                req=*(requests+j);
                if(req>=start && req<=end){
                    task=task+1;
                }
            }
         printf("%d\n",task);
        }
}
```

The nested for-loop here takes more than 30 seconds to run when inputs are of the order 50000. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're iterating through the entire list of inputs for each worker.  Instead, you can sort the list of inputs and then perform two binary searches for each worker to determine the indices of the tasks that are within the bounds

```
sortedInputs = Sort(inputs)
for(i=0;i<pro_start_length;i++){
  startIndex = BinarySearch(sortedInputs, *(pro_start+i));
  endIndex = BinarySearch(sortedInputs, *(pro_end+i));
  printf("%d\n",endIndex - startIndex)
}
```

You've got an initial O(n*log(n)) cost up front when you sort the inputs, but then the cost of each task count is O(log(n))

---

If instead you've got a fixed set of workers and a stream of requests (so it's not practical to sort the requests) then you could create a [Segment Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) of workers, and then for each request you would retrieve the set of workers who can fulfill the request.  This has the same complexity - O(n*log(n)) to create the segment tree, and O(log(n)) to query the tree for each request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should implement what you suggested and get back. Thanks.